# Enterprise Library 6, Exception Block, how to pick up custom exception class

Tags: c#, exception, web-config, enterprise-library

How to pick a custom exception class using the Entlib config Editor?
Trying to add a replace handler, therefore I need a custom exception
When I choose

> Add from file

I choose my assembly with the custom exceptions, but it doesnt show up in the list!
My custom exception class inherits form a BaseException class which inherits form System.Exception. I also tried it directly inheriting from Exception, but doesn't work neither.
Any suggestions. The most worse documentation I have ever seen in my life.

```
public class DummyException : System.Exception
    {

        public DummyException()
        { }

        public DummyException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public DummyException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        { }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added certain application blocks from entlib 6 into several projects of my solution using nuget.
I have also installed entlib 6 binaries from msdn.

Still don't know what the problem was, but I solved it like this:

Mark the solution file in solution explorer and press F4.
And under Entlib 6 binaries path, I have set it to the local installation/binaries folder of the entlib 6, in my case this was:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EnterpriseLib6

Now I can pick all custom exceptions!